# facet_wrap didn't work correctly depending on aes-setting

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have the following data frame:

```
test <- data.frame(x=c(1:8), y=c(8:1), Type=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), Condition=c("aa","bb","cc","dd"))

  x y Type Condition
1 1 8    A        aa
2 2 7    A        bb
3 3 6    A        cc
4 4 5    A        dd
5 5 4    B        aa
6 6 3    B        bb
7 7 2    B        cc
8 8 1    B        dd
```

When I run following command, I can get correct graphs like "test1".

```
q <- ggplot(test, aes(x, y, color=Type)) + geom_point(size=10) + labs(title = "test1")
q <- q + facet_wrap("Condition")
q
```

test1: [image: test1]

But actually I want to run the following command, because colnames of dataset I analyse are sometimes different.

```
q <- ggplot(test, aes(test[,1], test[,2], color=Type)) + geom_point(size=10) + labs(title = "test2")
q <- q + facet_wrap("Condition")
q
```

But the output is wrong like "test2": 
[image: test2]

Could someone please tell me a solution?
Thanks for your help!

---

Edit
This issue was solved by using aes_string() like this.

```
p <- ggplot(test, aes_string(x = colnames(test)[1], y = colnames(test)[2], color="Type")) + geom_point(size=10)
p <- p + facet_wrap("Condition")
p
```

Thank you all!

Comment: use `aes_string()` with indexed column names

Comment: Thank you for your critical comment! I tried aes_string(), and it works well. Thank you.

Comment: @rcs you can add your comment as an answer, that way everyone can see the question was answered (and you can get some rep :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot` doesn't like column indexing inside of `aes`. Use `aes_string()` instead with indexed column names:

```
ggplot(data=test,
       mapping=aes_string(x=names(test)[1], y=names(test)[2], color="Type")) + 
       geom_point(size=10) +
       facet_wrap(~ Condition)
```